# Memory Management with delete

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a little program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void inputArray(int*& p, int& n);
void print(int *p, int n);

int main() {
    int size = 0;
    int *arr;
    inputArray(arr, size);
}

void inputArray(int*& p, int& n) {
    int *q = new int[n]; int m = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) q[i] = p[i];
    cout << endl << "How many numbers to insert? "; cin >> n;
    delete p; 
    p = new int[n + m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) p[i] = q[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cin >> p[i + m];
    n += m;
}
```

The purpose of this program is to insert an array of integer. However, when I try to run the program with Code::Blocks on Ubuntu, it often says:

```
free(): invalid pointer: 0xb7646000 ***
```

after I input n.

However, when I remove `delete p;` , everything works well. However, I still want to know the problem. Can anyone tell what the problem is?

Comment: You have undefined behavior, `p` (which is `arr` from main) is not initialized and yet you try to delete it.

Comment: try `int *arr = null;`

Comment: Please never alter a pointer this way - you have a memory leak (even with a properly initialized `arr = 0`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 delete p;
```

You never allocated `p`, so when you try to `free` `p`, it can't.
It's like trying to access someone else's bank account, you may have the `name`, but you ain't allowed to *free* his `money`.

And *- just for the rant-* , try using more verbose variable names, it never hurts. Especially if you drunk-review your code in a year.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help and advice. But this is just a draft to test memory management so I don't think it is necessary to use meaningful-name variables.

Comment: @PeaNguyen  While i usually agree for small test-code, you never know when you're going to reuse small bits of your past.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning elements from the array `p`

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) q[i] = p[i];
```

But `p` was never allocated or assigned any values

```
int *arr;
inputArray(arr, size);   // Here "arr" is "p" within the function
```

This constitutes undefined behavior and will behave as such.